# Select tags with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I make a select elements with js?
Imagine somethings as:

```
<button class="" type="button" role="option"> Tag1 + </button>
<button class="" type="button" role="option"> Tag2 + </button>
```

And when I click on one of the buttons, it receives the active class as follows :

```
<button class="active" type="button" role="option"> Tag1 + </button>
<button class="" type="button" role="option"> Tag2 + </button>
```

Any help? Cheers everyone!

Comment: What did you feel? Please paste the code with the `<>` tool

Comment: Please paste your code and show us what you have tried?

Comment: <span type="button">??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a code like the following :

**Css :**

```
<style type="text/css">
        .active { 
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
        }
</style>
```

**Html :**

```
<button class="" type="button" id="tag1" onclick="addClass()" role="option">Tag1 </button>
```

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addClass() { 
       var tag1 = document.getElementById("tag1");
          
          if (tag1.classList.contains("active")) {
             tag1.classList.remove("active");
          } else {
             tag1.classList.add("active");
          }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Dadinaks ! Yeah, you got me. I will use that adding [i] because I've got more tags. The motivation for what I was using span role="option"  and type="button" is because i was making a select option as this: https://gyazo.com/7abb1bc2023654cb35b02954dddf0dc8

Comment: hi! this link doesn't work, can you rewrite the correct one so I can see what you want to do.

Comment: Ok may try this one here: https://i.gyazo.com/7abb1bc2023654cb35b02954dddf0dc8.png

Comment: ah okay, you need _Bootstrap_ for the css and _FontAwesome_ for the "+" icon. And on your image they are buttons with icon but not span... 
Try this link for **bootstrap** : 
[MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/buttons/)
and the next one for **font awesome** :
[FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/start)